# Problem with ardrone_driver

Tags: ros, ardrone2.0, tum-ardrone, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to roslaunch ardrone_driver. I have installed the ardrone_autonomy and tum_ardrone packages. when i try to roslaunch ardrone_driver i get this message:

> [ardrone_driver-1] process has died
> [pid 19905, exit code -11, cmd
> /opt/ros/hydro/ardrone_autonomy/bin/ardrone_driver
> __name:=ardrone_driver __log:=/home/michael/.ros/log/1b4dd950-f22c-11e3-a388-d0df9a5bc38d/ardrone_driver-1.log].
> log file:
> /home/michael/.ros/log/1b4dd950-f22c-11e3-a388-d0df9a5bc38d/ardrone_driver-1*.log
> all processes on machine have died,
> roslaunch will exit shutting down
> processing monitor... ... shutting
> down processing monitor complete done

And if i leave it long enough it says:

> Timeout when reading navdatas -
> resending a navdata request on port
> 5554

If someone knows any solution to this problem i would appreciate the help.

I'm using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. The ardrone is an AR Drone 2.0 firmware 2.3.3

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173485/problem-with-ardrone_driver/) by [Michael Panayiotou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18803/michael-panayiotou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-06-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which .launch file from ardone_autonomy did you try to launch?

Just to go over the basic, you start the driver with `rosrun ardrone_autonomy ardrone_driver`. Make sure your computer is connected to the drone's wi-fi.

---

Originally posted by [samudra](https://answers.ros.org/users/18845/samudra/) with karma: 36 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Michael Panayiotou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18803/michael-panayiotou/) on 2014-06-12**:
WiFi is on and connected to ardrone.i tried rosrun ardrone_autonomy ardrone_driver and i get this:

http://s7.postimg.org/c8xb5atga/Screenshot_from_2014_06_12_15_56_50.jpg

I even tried to connect it to my iphone and update it to 2.4.8 but i get stuck as you can see at the picture above.

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-06-12**:
open up the launch file you are trying to launch in a text editor. You'll see, that it will launch a couple of other nodes. To further investigate which node excactly is dying, you have to open up a couple of terminals and launch each node one after another. Post your findings in your question

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-06-12**:
The other option might be to just open up the log file described in your output ;) Usually there is more detailed information there too

**Comment by [samudra](https://answers.ros.org/users/18845/samudra/) on 2014-06-12**:
The picture looks OK to me. Can you get data from the drone say, with rostopic echo ardrone/navdata? If you connect to the drone from your phone, disconnect your computer.

If you want an example for flying AR.Drone with ROS, there is this tutorial: http://robohub.org/tag/parrot-ar-drone-tutorial/

**Comment by [Michael Panayiotou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18803/michael-panayiotou/) on 2014-06-13**:
i made this video to show you where is the problem. if anyone knows any solution to this i will appreciate the help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q48v_KG5ToM

**Comment by [samudra](https://answers.ros.org/users/18845/samudra/) on 2014-06-13**:
After you get those lines of [INFO], open *another* terminal, run: "rostopic list". You should see /ardrone/navdata among the output. If you do, the driver works. If you run "rostopic pub -1 /ardrone/reset std_msgs/Empty" you should see the drone LEDs change to red (green if you do it again).